# C# OpenAPI example decorator not working for Azure function request body

Tags: c#, azure-functions, openapi

I am trying to expose a C# Azure function's interface using an OpenAPI specification. I've added decorators to the function to capture the function's input query and path parameters as well as its response body. In all cases I can specify the type for values and examples.

However, I am unable to get this working for the request body on a POST or a PUT request. The OpenAPI specification is generated with the correct type information, but the example specification does not work. The generated OpenAPI specification simply omits the example.

Here is an example of the Azure function with some of the pertinent decorators:

```
[OpenApiOperation(
    operationId: "Create software application", 
    tags: new [] {"Software Applications"},
    Summary = "Create a new software application",
    Description = "Creates a new software application")]
[OpenApiRequestBody(
    contentType: "application/json",
    bodyType: typeof(SoftwareApplicationResource),
    Example = typeof(SoftwareApplicationRequestExample),
    Required = true,
    Description = "The software application to create")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> CreateSoftwareApplication(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "softwareApplications")] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
}
```

I have the `bodyType` type defined as follows:

```
public class SoftwareApplicationResource
{
    [OpenApiProperty(Nullable = true, Description = "The ID for the software application, or null if not yet assigned")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [OpenApiProperty(Nullable = false, Description = "The registration ID for the software application")]
    public string registrationId { get; set; }

    [OpenApiProperty(Nullable = false, Description = "The name for the software application")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [OpenApiProperty(Nullable = true, Description = "The description for the software application")]
    public string description { get; set; }

    [OpenApiProperty(Nullable = true, Default = SoftwareApplicationLifecycleStatus.Active, Description = "The lifecycle status for the software application")]
    public SoftwareApplicationLifecycleStatus lifecycleStatus { get; set; }
}
```

The `Example` type is defined as:

```
public class SoftwareApplicationResponseExample : OpenApiExample<SoftwareApplicationResource>
{
    public override IOpenApiExample<SoftwareApplicationResource> Build(NamingStrategy namingStrategy = null)
    {
        this.Examples.Add(OpenApiExampleResolver.Resolve(
            "Software application response",
            new SoftwareApplicationResource() 
            { 
                id = "e2c6b163-1a65-4b8f-ac3f-74061ea254a9",
                registrationId = "0df858f4-11b3-48b8-aed0-c48788f9c3bd",
                name = "My Software Application",
                description = "A new software application to end world hunger",
                lifecycleStatus = SoftwareApplicationLifecycleStatus.Active
            },
            namingStrategy));
        return this;
    }
}
```

With this in place, I get the following in my generated OpenAPI specification:

```
"post": {
        "tags": [
          "Software Applications"
        ],
        "summary": "Create a new software application",
        "description": "Creates a new software application",
        "operationId": "Create software application",
        "consumes": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "body",
            "description": "The software application to create",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/softwareApplicationResource"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
            ...
        }
```

AS you can see, the request body is represented as an input parameter, but there is no reference to its example. The same mechanism works for me when describing the response body but fails for the request body.

Am I missing something here?